# How to edit the plist file for IAP

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I want to implement IAP in my app, and the products are non-consumables. I have tried to use [EBPurchase](https://github.com/ebutterfly/EBPurchase) and [MKStoreKit](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/using-mkstorekit-in-your-apps/). They both mention i should edit plist file to set up configuration, like adding a array of products into plist. Can anyone teach me how to edit the plist? Do we need to change Bundle identifier? Any resources are helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a peak at this tutorial: [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: @Jeremy I have read that. It just tells us to edit plist, but not how to.

Comment: You can read/write plist using [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  Also, take a look at the [Property List Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the plist in Xcode after you add it to the project just like you would edit any other plist (or .m file or .h file). So, using MKStoreKit as an example:

1. Follow the instructions to add the MKStoreKit files to your app in XCode
2. Find `MKStoreKitConfigs.plist` and open it so that it appears in the middle pane of Xcode (it will look like a grid)
3. Right Click or ctrl-clik on the plist to show the context menu and "Add Row"
4. Type in the Name of your key then choose the type from the drop down and enter a value
5. Look at the sample file to see how NSArrays and NSDictionaries use the little triangle icon to expand and collapse themselves.